# MySql: Unique index only, when other field is false

Tags: php, mysql

I have a shop-database. So far, you can only buy something when you are a registered user, so I have a unique index over the customer email-addresses, because every customer should only be registered once in the database.

Now I want to offer an order without register yourself ("order as guest"). The idea was to add a field to the user-database "guest BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT false" to indicate if the user was created as a guest. But as allowing orders as guests, it would be possible to have the same email-address inside the user-table more than once (because one user could order mutliple times as a guest).

So now I would need something like: The field "email-address" should be unique, but only when the field "guest" is false.

Is it possible to do that with mysql-features or do I have to remove the unique index from email and make sure inside my code that every email should be unique, but only if it's not a guest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily do this in MySQL.  Other databases offer filtered indexes and computed columns, both of which make this possible.

One option would be to have a guestid that is unique, but has a single value (say -1, but not `NULL`) for non-guests.  Then you can create a unique index on `(emailaddress, guestid)`.

You could even maintain such a column by using a trigger.  Of course, if you are using triggers, you could enforce the constraint that way as well.